# In Javascript, is myObject == null a valid way to handle checking for undefined as well?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is `myObject == null` a valid way to handle checking for undefined as well as null?

JSLint would prefer that I do `(myObject === undefined || myObject === null)`

What Would Doug Crockford Do? (WWDCD)

Comment: Yes, it is a way to check for both. Crockford would suggest what JSLint suggests (obviously) because `==` is voodoo to him

Comment: WWDCD === JSLint advice.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Or `==`? Hehe

Comment: @Ian nope, Crockford and `==` in the same expression would yield a syntax error. `;)`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Snap, you're right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's a nice way to check for both. The language specification [states](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) (regarding `==` for comparing values of different types):

> 2) If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
>
> 3) If x is undefined and y is null, return true.

Here *x* and *y* are the terms of a comparison `x == y`. When you're comparing `x == null`, it will only be true if `x` is `undefined`, or `null` itself.

---

Just to be clear, when we say "undefined" here we mean the value `undefined`, not variables that are not defined (those produce a ReferenceError whenever they're used, except with `typeof`).

---

And regarding WWDCD, I'll quote Ian: *Crockford would suggest what JSLint suggests (obviously) because == is voodoo to him*. That means "use `===`, never `==`". So this would be a non-question for him.

Comment: +1 for the simplicity. `== null` is the simplest way to test for `undefined` and `null` values, this is also what jQuery uses internally. Just be aware that trying to compare with a not defined variable will throw a type ReferenceError (`typeof` should be used in this case).

Comment: You might want to respond to the Crockford reference/question too. Although it's pretty obvious because JSLint's answer is Crockford's answer basically

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I wasn't thinking of undefined variables (just values), but added a note about that.

Comment: Yeah same here, adding a note about that for the completeness' sake (and future JS starters that may come to read this thread) doesn't hurt though. `:P`

Comment: @Ian Added a quote from your comment (you pretty much nailed it), plus a bit of extra explanation.

Comment: @bfavaretto Cool, no reason to quote me but thanks :) I just think it's silly to completely dismiss `==` because this is a great use case for it (although it can easily be changed to `=== undefined || === null`) but that's no fun, and stinks to have to turn off the `==` detection feature just for this

Comment: @collapsar If you're implying I was your downvoter, I wasn't.

Comment: @bfavaretto: i'm not. your answer is comprehensive and correct, mine was neither. sorry for the ambiguous wording.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `myObject == null` a valid way to handle checking for undefined as well as null?

Yes. As [defined by the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3), `null` and `undefined` are the only two values that equal `null`.

> JSLint would prefer that I do `(myObject === undefined || myObject === null)`

Then it doesn't understand your intention. It's not the first time. Or it (and its creator Crockford) want you to write explicit code, to be correctly understood by everyone who doesn't know all of Javascript's internals.

Answer (score 1):

Running this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
    var variable = undefined;

    if (typeof variable === 'undefined') console.log("variable is undefined");
    if (variable == null) {
        console.log("variable is null");
    } else {
        console.log("variable is not null");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="test()">
</body>
```

Returned the output

```
variable is undefined
variable is null
```

So... it seems to work. But I also seem to remember something odd about null vs undefined. Or maybe that was in another language-they start to blur together after a while.

Regardless, the answer that @collapsar gave is probably the cleanest way to do it as it checks for all cases.