# Checking JavaScript object for null subtelty

Tags: javascript

I believe I have found cases where I need to check for both undefined and null for a javascript object as follows:

```
if (x !== undefined && x != null && x.length > 0) {...}
```

However, in a recent upgrade of JetBrains tools, it tells me that this is sufficient

```
if (x != undefined && x.length > 0) {...}
```

My question is, I'm just wanting to insure that a string "x" has a length of non-zero and is not undefined or null (with the least amount tests).

Thoughts?

Comment: If you want a string of length > 0, check that `typeof x === 'string' && x.length > 0`.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what you're asking here,

Comment: What do you believe in?

Comment: @AurélienOoms, **World Peace**, if you pointed the question to me. ``)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Javascript, is myObject == null a valid way to handle checking for undefined as well?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137996/in-javascript-is-myobject-null-a-valid-way-to-handle-checking-for-undefined) (since the answer is yes, it works the other way round as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if `foo === undefined` will trigger the error *foo is not defined*. See [variable === undefined vs. typeof variable === "undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined)

The [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) in CoffeeScript compiles to

```
typeof face !== "undefined" && face !== null
```

Edit:

[Matt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421995/checking-javascript-object-for-null-subtelty/18422165#comment27063730_18421995) is better if you only want to check for strings:

```
typeof x === 'string' && x.length > 0
```

Answer (score 5):

in javascript

```
undefined == null // true
undefined === null // false
```

so checking with `==` for `undefined` makes the `==` check for `null` redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (x && x.length)
```

as `undefined`, `null` and `0` are all falsy values.

EDIT:
as you seem to know that `x` should be a `string`, you can also just use `if (x)` as an empty string is also falsy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_.isNull` from [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) a JavaScript library provides a whole mess of useful functional programming helpers.

**_.isNull(object)**

Returns true if the value of object is null.

```
_.isNull(null);
=> true
_.isNull(undefined);
=> false
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use and it's the most concise.  It covers: 
undefined, null, NaN, 0, "" (empty string), or false. We can therefore say that "object" is truthy.

```
if(object){
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (!x) {
  // is emtpy
}
```

Comment: The case I'm almost always looking for and I'd like to have a really good "always use" pattern is   Is it a non null, non empty string

Answer (score 0):

To check against `null` AND `undefined` AND "empty string" you can just write

```
if(!x) {
   // will be false for undefined, null and length=0
}
```

BUT you need to be sure that your variable is defined! Otherwise this will cause an error.

If you are checking for a value in an `object` (e.g. the `window` object), you can always use that. E.g. for checking for `localStorage` support:

```
var supports = {
    localStorage: !!window.localStorage
}
```